# sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table in the following format

```
ID   Revision     DocType
1     R1            1
2     R2            1
3     R2            2
4     R3            1
```

where Revision can be duplicated but DocType is unique per Revision. How can I write an SQL query to select a single record by providing Revision as a parameter?

Comment: I don't follow your logic. The revision column is not unique, yet you only want to retrieve one row with a given revision value. Maybe you wish to explain this a bit further as to what you are expecting in that one row and how is it going to be related to the other two fields? By the way, I downvoted you to 0 as it's an impossible question in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Since Revision can be duplicate, the only way you can get a lone record by passing in a Revision as parameter is by doing:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID,Revision,DocType 
from Revision 
where Revision=@RevisionPassedIn
```

If you can provide DocType as well, then you could uniquely select the record you are looking for:

```
SELECT ID,Revision,DocType 
from Revision 
where Revision=@RevisonPasseIn AND Doctype=@DocTypePassedIn
```

Comment: We are making a lot of assumptions here. I'd probably wait till the OP provides more info as per my comment to his question before deciding on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've just described why you can't really achieve what you want - there can be multiple rows with the same `Revision` value.

If you're happy with getting the *first* row with that value, you can do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
WHERE Revision = @Revision
ORDER BY DocType -- or whatever criteria you want
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 could select either one of the rows, depending in which physical order the data is stored. SELECT UNIQUE would be more appropiate, however the question needs clarification..

Comment: Note the `ORDER BY` clause here, @Frank. *That* determines what *first row* means here, not the physical data structure.

Comment: However, Revision is not being sorted with ORDER BY, so TOP 1 would be the first one that DocType sorts on.. there's a difference!

Comment: Of course the Revision column isn't affecting the sort order, @Frank. This query will select a single row that matches the query criteria specified, deterministically selecting the row that appears at the top of the sort order (the first row in the OP's sample data above, given a standard collation). What else could you expect? It will **not** *"select either one of the rows, depending in which physical order the data is stored."*

Comment: What I'm trying to summarize is that TOP 1 will not always guarantee the same results where Revision could have duplicate values. How would SELECT UNIQUE differ from TOP 1?

Comment: It absolutely *will*, given the OP's sample data, @Frank. If multiple rows have the same DocType? Then use another `ORDER BY` criteria, like I suggest in my answer. If the *entire row* is a dupe? Then the argument gets philisophical pretty rapidly - why does it matter which row you get back?

Comment: two or more rows don't have to be exact duplicates. Having same values in Revision and DocType columns in two or more rows would suffice to render different results for TOP 1 or UNIQUE, depending in which physical order the data is stored!.. Even a CLUSTERED INDEX on any of these two columns would render differnt results for TOP 1 because the CLUSTERING is not maintained once new rows are INSERTED.

Comment: @Frank! Read my answer, and my earlier comment, again. *"-- or whatever criteria you want" "If multiple rows have the same DocType? Then use another ORDER BY criteria, like I suggest in my answer."* If the OP can have multiple rows with the same Revision-Doctype tuple value, they'll need to pick a different way to order.